# Use inner join, left join or right join for join 2 tables

Tags: mysql, subquery, project, union

I'm realizing a project which raises me the next tables:

For being more specific: First table:

'docs' => doc_id, doc_type_type_id, clients_cli_id
where doc_type_type_id

1. invoices
2. reference guides

Second Table:

'client' => cli_id

What I try to do is to join Client with doc that My query is:

Show Client with his invoice and reference guide:

```
SELECT c.cli_name, d1.doc_file as f1 , d2.doc_file as f2 FROM clients c INNER JOIN docs d1 ON d1.client_cli_id = c.cli_id INNER JOIN docs d2 ON d2.client_cli_id = c.cli_id WHERE d1.doc_fec=d2.doc_fec
```

Comment: SO is not a school or tutoring service, you need to learn the basics yourself. Then post your code if you can't get it working, and we'll help you fix it. You can learn about SQL joins here: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from docs
    inner join client on docs.clients_cli_id = client.cli_id
    where doc_type_type_id = 1
```

Something in this format should give you all invoices joined to client.

Comment: You could have a result like client had in the same record associated with 
doc_type_type_id = 1 and doc_type_type_id = 2

Comment: If you need both doc_types, then you would just leave off the "where doc_type_type_id =1" from the query.

Comment: How to explain? I'm sure my english is bad. What happens is that in parallel to display the invoice, waybill and client.